# OpenCV, how can we normalize a Mat min to max and max to min?

Tags: opencv

I want to normalize a `Mat` to the min value goes to 255 and max goes to 0 (normalize the `Mat` between **0~255**).

For example, if we have an array like `[0.02, 0.002, 0.0002]` after normalization I want to get a result like this: `[3, 26, 255]`, but now when I am using `NORM_MINMAX` I got `[255, 26, 3]`.

But I did not find any function to do the inverted operation of the `NORM_MINMAX`.

**Code used:**

```
cv::Mat mat(10, 10, CV_64F);
mat.setTo(0);
mat.row(0) = 0.02;
mat.row(1) = 0.002;
mat.row(2) = 0.0002;
cv::normalize(mat, mat, 255, 0, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
mat.convertTo(mat, CV_8UC1);
std::cout << mat << std::endl;
```

**Result is:**

```
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26;
   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

But I want the inverse of the above result.

**Update:** When I subtract 255 from the mat like:

```
cv::subtract(255, mat, mat, mat); // the last mat acts as mask
std::cout << mat << std::endl;
```

**Result is:**

```
[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
 229, 229, 229, 229, 229, 229, 229, 229, 229, 229;
 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

Comment: Python or C++ ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell c++

Comment: you can do something like `result = 255-result` after the normalization

Comment: @api55 Question updated, but the result is not something I want.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil The answer of the api55 is right and it works

Comment: Ahh now I understand... However is not an easy problem... first, `[0.02, 0.002, 0.0002]` does not give `[255, 26, 3]` you also have 0 in the initial numbers. So  `[0.02, 0.002, 0.0002, 0]` gives `[255, 26, 3]` but then you want to invert the values except the 0, which AFAIK there is no easy way to do it.... maybe you can do a lookup table and use LUT function? normalize won't do, NORM_MINMAX does is a scaling to make it fit in 0-255 which can be done with a formula. If you invert the order then the formula won't work (or you get what I commented before).

Comment: @api55 I have already done it in the question, you can see the result, it is wrong, you. You can see that for 0.002 it gives 229, which it must be 25.5 (26), so it is wrong.

Comment: Why the question got Down vote, if you anyone cannot solve this, please skip and go. But it is really a problem, my self did a lot of searching to achieve this in the best way, but did not find. I know how to calculate manually, but because I am using in a real-time application I think maybe there will be the best way to do this.

Comment: I saw it, and I agree with you, my first comment is wrong. What I said later is that if you only have those values `[0.02, 0.002, 0.0002]` you get something like `[255, 23.18,0]`, because you do not count the value 0. Also, NORM_MINMAX only will change the scale, preserving the proportional distance between the numbers. In your example you want to assign different proportions to the numbers, and this can't be achieved with a formula. The only way I can think up is creating a [Look up table](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab55b8d062b7f5587720ede032d34156f).

Comment: @api55 The 0 values are what I have masked out, I just want to calculate none zero elements, so the NORM_MINMAX works well in forwarding operation, but I want the same result in reverse as well. But unfortunately, there is no function in OpenCV that can do this.

Comment: I mean that the 0 values are taken in account in the normalize operation. As far as I know, the reverse keeping the same numbers is not possible with a mathematical formula. You will need to take all the unique non-zero numbers, order them and change them. I can give you an example of that with LUT, but it probably is not super efficient... BTW, I did not vote yet on this question...

Comment: So it becomes a challenge to who they are experts in calculating the complex problem.

Comment: I will consider it a hard problem :( since there is simple formula to do it, and even if I may have an idea to do it, it will be probably inefficient, nevertheless I can try to post it later if you want.

Comment: @api55 Already done, you can take a look. This challenge I won!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the way how to calculate, below are the steps:

By using inverse proportions formula, we can easily calculate the inverse of the `NORM_MINMAX`

```
x = a*b/c
```

Where the **a**= min value of the mat element, **b**=255 (max value), and **c**= the element which we want to calculate it.

```
cv::Mat mat(10, 10, CV_64F);

mat.setTo(0);
mat.row(0) = 0.02;
mat.row(1) = 0.002;
mat.row(2) = 0.0002;
std::cout << mat<< std::endl;

// craete a mask
cv::Mat mask(mat.size(), CV_8U);
mask.setTo(0);
mask.row(0) = 255;
mask.row(1) = 255;
mask.row(2) = 255;

// find the min value
double min;
cv::minMaxLoc(mat, &min, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, mask);
std::cout << "min=" << min << std::endl;

// unfortunately opencv divide operation does not support mask, so we need some extra steps to perform.
cv::Mat result, maskNeg;
cv::divide(min*255, mat, result); // this is the magic line
cv::bitwise_not(mask, maskNeg);
mat.copyTo(result, maskNeg);
std::cout << result << std::endl;

// convert to 8bit
result .convertTo(result , CV_8UC1);
std::cout << "the final result:" << std::endl;
std::cout << temp << std::endl;
```

**And the outputs:**

```
original mat
[0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02;
 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002;
 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

min=0.0002

the calculated min-max
[2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55;
 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5;
 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

 the final result:
[  3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3;
  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26;
 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

Yes, It is what I want.

Comment: Good to see that you managed it :D get an upvote for your effort ;)